# Iterating thru the list and updating data can't find the item in the db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a list in a view with values that need to be updated.
When calling the http method, I am going thru the list components and looking into the database for a item with the right Id and updating the Grade value. My problem is that I can't return the right item from the database, it always returns null. I have checked with debugging, the item from the list with the Id that I am looking for has the right value, but I can't return the item from db.
I have also tried with the sql raw query and it gives me the same error.
This is my code - the var exam is always null :

```
public ActionResult UpdateExams(ExamsList examList)
        {
            var examVM = new ExamViewModel
            {
                Professor = _context.Professor.ToList()
            };

            examVM.ExamsList = examList;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var GradesList = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 5; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    GradesList.Add(i);
                }

                var GradesListSL = new SelectList(GradesList);

                return PartialView("ExamsTable", examList);

            }

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < examList.ExamDetails.Count; i++)
                {
                      var exam = _context.Exam.Single(e => e.Id == examList.ExamDetails[i].Id);
//                    var exam = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Exam>(@"SELECT Id as Id,Grade as Grade
//FROM Exam  
//WHERE Id={0})
//", examList.ExamDetails[i].Id).ToList();

                        exam.Grade = examList.ExamDetails[i].Grade == 0 ? exam.Grade : examList.ExamDetails[i].Grade;


                }
                //  _context.SaveChanges();

                TempData["InsertingExam"] = "Success!";
                // return RedirectToAction("Create", "Exams");
                return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Edit", "Exams") });
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException ex) //DbContext
            {

                string exception = ex.StackTrace + ex.Message;
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", exception);
                return View(examVM);
                throw;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string exception = ex.StackTrace + ex.Message;
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", exception);
                return View(examVM);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? `.Single` does not return null - it throws an exception if nothing matches.

Comment: The problem was that I needed to create the main model class from this view model and then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to do the database operation with the view model class.
After I added creating the model class from the view model everything worked just fine.